# poll/select unable to receive error with libfuse

Tags: c, fuse

How does application waiting on select/poll receive errors with libfuse. 
I have modified fsel.c and fselclient.c code provided in libfuse examples to explain the issue which I am facing.

fsel.c: function fsel_poll().

```
static int fsel_poll(const char *path, struct fuse_file_info *fi,
         struct fuse_pollhandle *ph, unsigned *reventsp)
{
    printf("on fuse poll called \r\n");
    return -ENOENT; // return error on poll
}
```

fselclient.c : application

```
while (1) {
    static char buf[4096];
    fd_set rfds;
    fd_set wfds;
    fd_set efds;
    int rc;

    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_ZERO(&wfds);
    FD_ZERO(&efds);

    FD_SET(fds, &rfds);
    FD_SET(fds, &wfds);
    FD_SET(fds, &efds);

    rc = select(nfds, &rfds, &wfds, &efds, NULL);

    printf(" rc value in select %d errno %d \r\n", rc, errno);
    if (rc < 0) {
        printf("Select error \r\n");
        perror("select");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

With above code modification, I see that select unblocks with **rfds and wfds set** with **rc as 2**, but actually it **should be -1** since I am always returning error (**ENOENT**) in fuse poll handling function.

Has anyone faced this issue with fuse , If yes how do I return errors on select/poll ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You don't zero out `wfds` or `efds`, meaning their contents will be *indeterminate* and give you *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: thanks for your response. even with FD_ZERO(&wfds) and FD_ZERO(&efds), I face the same issue.